# get_option('admin_email') not working in wordpress when using ajax call

Tags: php, javascript

So I've been working in Wordpress lately with Ajax and I managed to get some stock data into my site from my database. However, I am now trying to use Ajax to load Wordpress posts into my left sidebar, which requires the use of Wordpress functions and it seems as if I am not doing this properly.get_option() shows NULL on this.

JS

```
 url:"<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/sendContactForm.php",//request URL
                type:"POST",//Request type GET/POST
                data: $(_this).serialize()
```

PHP(sendContactForm.php)

```
$result = new stdClass();
$from = $_REQUEST['email'];
$message = $_REQUEST['message'];
$sender = $_REQUEST['email'];
$result->message = $message;  
$result->subject = $_REQUEST['name'] . " send you a message";
$result->to = "get_option('admin_email');

$result->to = "get_option('admin_email');  showing NULL
```

Comment: I suspect the double quotes are the reason for the no result returned, try removing the quotes,e.g. `$result->to = "get_option('admin_email');`. Alternatively you can `$email = get_option('admin_email');` and parse that to variable to the location where you need it in your script.

Comment: That is typo error.it shown NULL in ajax but return correct in wordpress php files

Comment: Okay, I will answer but it will be messy.

Comment: Okey.Give a clear answer please

Comment: `sendContactForm.php` seems to be a custom PHP script: when it is directly executed, as you are doing by sending a direct request to that file, you are out of WordPress. Use Ajax API, REST API or load WordPress inside your custom PHP script. Similar questions has been asked hundreds of times.

Comment: you should have any form handling directly in a php file in your theme. This is just not going to work in all kinds of ways

Comment: @cybmeta He definitely wants to do ajax call here. Can you please explain how to do that? I am his colleague.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I confess that I'm slightly confused by how your sending email function loads posts into your sidebar...the code does not seem to be doing the thing that you described.

Are you loading WordPress in sendContactForm.php? Is what you've shown here the only code in sendContactForm.php?

`get_option()` is a WordPress function, so you need to load WordPress to do this.  This is usually done by putting something at the top of your php file like:

`require('../../../wp-load.php');`

But that's a bit hacky.

The proper way to do AJAX in WordPress is to send your POST request to `/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php` with an parameter like `action=sendContactForm` and then create an action hook like this:

```
add_action('wp_ajax_sendContactForm', 'my_email_function');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_sendContactForm', 'my_email_function');

function my_email_function() {
    // process request here
    wp_die();
}
```

Read more about this at: https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins

Comment: `require('../../../wp-load.php');` will fail because `wp-load.php` is not required to be there and can theoretically be anywhere

Comment: Sure. If you are using a non-standard WordPress directory structure, or if the file you're doing the `require` in is not in the theme's root directory, then you should replace the path with the correct path to your own site's `wp-load.php` - basically, requiring the `wp-load.php` from the root of WordPress, wherever that is, is a possible solution. But proper use of `admin-ajax.php` is better.

Comment: the point is that when you not developing something for distribution, lets say you develop a plugin, this kind of assumption will make the plugin fail sometimes. If you know where the file is, you can do anything you want, but you can't do it on other people's installs.

Comment: Thanks Mark. You're right and I agree. That's why I said using `wp-load.php` was "a bit hacky" and subsequently recommended using the `admin-ajax.php` approach.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the email address in the WordPress code and add it to a data attribute like:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="whatever-your-class" data-email="<?php echo get_option('admin_email'); ?>">
    </div>
</div>
```

And then in your AJAX code, something like this:

```
$post = $(this);
$.ajax({
   url: "test.php",   // where you are posting to
   type: "GET",
   data: { email: $($email).attr("data-email") }, 
   success: function(response) {
      alert(response);  
   }
});
```

Does that make sense? You are echoing the email address on to your page template and then using jQuery to grab it and place it in your AJAX call. It's messy but it should work.

Comment: Hmmm, @magicroundabout seems to mention that you are getting the data from a WordPress site, meaning that you want the posts on a static or separate project. It that the case?